# Console.ReadLine() equivalent for TextBox KeyDown or other event?

Tags: c#, textbox, readline

How can I return the contents of a TextBox when its KeyDown event is fired? I want to make a Console.ReadLine() equivalent. So for example:

```
Write("Hi! Enter your name...");
Write(ReadFromTextBox());
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I think you need `Console.ReadKey`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy For what? I'm trying to return the text of a textbox in the same fashion the console returns text from Console.ReadLine()..

Comment: Your title says that you are looking for equivalent of TextBox KeyDown event. I don't know what for

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` already returns a `string`, if that's not what you want, you should provide a better example.

Comment: public string ReadFromTextBox()
{
    return myTextBox.Text;
} Are you missing the part that wait for a keystroke?

Comment: @Larry Yes. I'm trying to make that method wait for the user to type text into the textbox and hit enter. Then the return value will be the textbox's text.

Comment: There are fundamentally different input models between console applications and forms applications. Forms applications handle input via *events* - the events fire when something interesting happens, and its up to you to put code inside there to react to the event. In console applications, you *ask* for input when you want it and wait until that input is available. Don't try to build applications in one style when inside the other type of application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the textChanged event.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
}
```

And if you want to read only after the user presses enter:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);

}
```

Comment: Alright, but how can I return textBox1.Text as a string to a calling method?

Comment: ahhh I see... That is a fun problem. I would probably solve it by  the keyDown event would throw an event that you would catch. 

Or your function would be in another thread and waiting for an event or bool that enter has been pressed.....

Comment: Yes I'm trying to solve it right now.. It's quite challenging when you think about it carefully..